# How to update JTable using JTextFields

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I have it so when I click a row, all the information is displayed on JTextFields, but I was wondering how do I then use that to update the entries if a user then makes a change?

```java
String[] columnNames = {"ID","FirstName","Surname","Email","Phone","Street","City","County","Eircode"};
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
while(rs.next()) {
    String ID = rs.getString("idCustomer");
    String FirstName = rs.getString("FirstName");
    String Surname = rs.getString("Surname");
    String Email = rs.getString("Email");
    String Phone = rs.getString("Phone");
    String Street = rs.getString("Street");
    String City = rs.getString("City");
    String County = rs.getString("County");
    String Eircode = rs.getString("Eircode");
    // Row data
    String[] data = {ID, FirstName, Surname, Email, Phone, Street, City, County, Eircode};
    // Add row
    tableModel.addRow(data);
}

// JTable
table = new JTable(tableModel);
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
pTable.add(new JScrollPane(table)); // Allows column names to be displayed

ListSelectionModel model = table.getSelectionModel();
model.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
        id1.setText(table.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0).toString());
        fName1.setText(table.getValueAt(selectedRow, 1).toString());
        surname1.setText(table.getValueAt(selectedRow, 2).toString());
        email1.setText(table.getValueAt(selectedRow, 3).toString());
        phone1.setText(table.getValueAt(selectedRow, 4).toString());
        street1.setText(table.getValueAt(selectedRow, 5).toString());
        city1.setText(table.getValueAt(selectedRow, 6).toString());
        county1.setText(table.getValueAt(selectedRow, 7).toString());
        eircode1.setText(table.getValueAt(selectedRow, 8).toString());

    }
});
```

Comment: You would have an add and/or an update JButton.  The ActionListener of the add or update JButton would get the text from the JTextFields and add or update the Customer record to a java.util.List of Customer records.

Comment: Not sure why the above comment talks about a "Customer" record. You would not update the All you need to do is use the getText(...) method of each text field and invoke the setValueAt(...) method for the selected row and each column..I