# How to use one JTable to show information on another

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

How do I get information from selecting a Jtable row and then providing relevant information from a different table onto another one? I want to display my Invoice information and once I click one, I want to display the Customer and Products related to it.

```
try {
            Connection connection;
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "root", "");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT I.idInvoice, C.idCustomer, C.FirstName, C.Surname, C.Phone, C.Street, C.City, C.County, C.Eircode, P.idProduct, P.PName, P.Price, P.Brand, I.QuantityOrder\n" +
                    "FROM `Invoice` I \n" +
                    "JOIN `Customer` C on I.idCustomer = C.idCustomer \n" +
                    "JOIN `PRODUCT` P on I.idProduct = P.idProduct LIMIT 0, 1000";
            PreparedStatement pstat = null;
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
            // Column name array
            String[] columnNames = {"idInvoice", "Date", "QuantityOrdered", "idCustomer", "idProduct"};
            String[] columnNames1 = {"idProduct", "pName", "Brand", "Price", "Quantity"};
            DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
            DefaultTableModel tableModel1 = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
            // Get data from database
            while (rs.next()) {
                String idI = rs.getString("idInvoice");
                String idC = rs.getString("idCustomer");
                String idP = rs.getString("idProduct");
                String date = rs.getString("Date");
                String qOrdered = rs.getString("quantityOrder");
                // Row data
                String[] data = {idI, date, qOrdered, idC, idP};
                // Add date to rows
                tableModel.addRow(data);
            }
            // JTable creation and customization
            table = new JTable(tableModel);
            table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            pTable.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66207747/how-to-update-jtable-using-jtextfields

Comment: @camickr Is there an example you could point me towards?

Comment: 1) I don't understand your question so no I can't help. If you want two tables then you need data in two tables. How that data is created is up to you. 2) You were given help in your last question and you didn't respond indicating if the suggestions helped or not. So it appears you don't even take the time to read suggestions anyways.